# How to get the original name of the location?

Tags: android, geocoder

I want to get the original name of the location, without translating it to the users default languages (without setting a `Locale.DEFAULT`). How can I achieve this? I've tried to set a `null` in the function, but my app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but with this line you get the actual locale of the cellphone:

```
String localeString = String.valueOf(getResources().getConfiguration().locale)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can choose your favorite language in last word:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.757178,%2051.375478&language=en